# Java Ejecutar un método cuando el programa se minimiza

Tags: java

Tengo en mi programa de Java en el IDE NetBeans un metodo que solo quiero que se ejecute cuando el programa se minimize.

¿Hay alguna manera de hacer esto posible?

Comment: Sirve manipulando un evento de `WindowListener` mas precisamente con el método `windowIconified()`. Oracle ofrece un claro tutorial acerca de ese apartado y mas. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/windowlistener.html

Comment: Me sirvió perfectamente el WindowListener, muchas gracias

Answer (score 1):

Existe un método en java de la clase Frame que detecta el estado actual del mismo llamado [getExtendedState()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Frame.html#getExtendedState--). Entre los estados que admite se encuentra [ICONIFIED](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Frame.html#ICONIFIED), que corresponde al estado minimizado de la aplicación.

```
 if ((f.getExtendedState() == Frame.ICONIFIED)) { 
     System.out.println("Estado minimizado");
 }
```

Comment: ¿f es un Frame de AWT o un JFrame de Swing?

Comment: EL usuario nunca dijo que fuera un Frame, tal vez por eso tu respuesta no ha sido aceptada

Comment: @RuslanLópez `f` es un `Frame` de `AWT`.

Comment: Puede ser, sí. Faltaría que hubiera sido más claro.

Comment: Esa es la razón por la que no todas las preguntas deben de ser respondidas. Si en algún momento el usuario regresa y especifica que se trata de un JFrame tú te llenarás de votos negativos y tu biena intención se perderá además de que tu reputación se dañará en el sitio. Trata de pedir al usuario que agregue ma´s detalles si tu respuesta no cubre todos los casos posibles.

Comment: Es un jframe, no llegue a probar esta solución use la implementación WindowListener y me sirvió perfectamente, doy punto positivo a la respuesta porque seguramente también hubiera funcionado, muchas gracias y disculpen si no había entrado antes.